# Есть ли будущее у c#

Tags: c#

Господа, простите за немного холиварный вопрос, но хочу услышать ваше мнение.

Посмотрев на количество вакансий, прочитав разные аналитические статьи и взглянув на диаграммы популярности языков программирования появилось ощущение, что C# очень теряет свои позиции. Например даже если самому подумать, то выходит, что веб направление это PHP и JSP в первую очередь, ASP идет после них. Мобильное направление это Android и приложения под IOS, WinPhone опять отстает и очень серьезно. Проектов десктопных приложений я уже давненько не встречал ни под какую платформу.
И получается грустная картина, что .Net рассчитанный только под WinOS очень теряет позиции и в дальнейшем будет не совсем актуально. 
А вы что думаете по этому вопросу ?

Comment: ну а вы какие-то данные в подтверждение этого мнения можете привести? Все-таки не очень хочется комментировать голословные утверждения

Comment: http://dou.ua/lenta/articles/language-rating-jan-2014/
http://ain.ua/2014/09/30/542793
http://githut.info/

Хотя бы эти. Здесь c# далеко не на первом месте
http://truepositive.org/langs.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Начну с того, что раз вы приводите данные украинских сайтов, то, вероятно, вас интересует именно этот рынок труда. К сожалению я не знаком с особенностями IT-рынка Украины, поэтому воздержус от комментариев именно по этой стране.

В общем и целом у вас тут целый ряд довольно голословных утверждений. 
Начнем по порядку.

Первое. C# всегда был менее популярен, чем Java или PHP. Причем, если в России он просто менее популярен, нежели Java, то скажем в США значительно менее популярен. Тому было много причины, в частности, более раннее появление Java и ее же кроссплатформенность. Поэтому я бы не стал утверждать, что это свидетельство заката C#

Второе. C# очень бурно развивается. Судите сами - дженерики, анонимные методы, делегаты, лямбды, linq, удобная модель написания асинхронного кода, грядущий roslyn - все это очень крутые вещи, которые свидетельствуют о динамичности развития языка. Сравните скажем с PHP, который никак не может разродиться новой версией, или хотя бы с Java, который только год назад обзавелся лямбдами. Нет, конечно не в лямбдах счастье, но само по себе отсутствие застоя в развитии языка говорит в его пользу.

Третье. У C# есть одно очень важное преимущество перед рядом других языков - он поддерживается крупной корпорацией. Сами знаете какой. Это в определенной степени является залогом уверенности в будущем языка. Microsoft конечно иногда любит закапывать свои детища, но, думается, это все же не тот случай - слишком много всего у них завязано на этот язык.

Четвертое. .NET наконец становится кроссплатформенным. Microsoft вынашивает наполеоновские планы по экспансии на рынок мобильной разработки, взаимодействуя с Xamarin, вовсю развивает ASP.NET, который скоро можно будет разворачивать на любых серверах. Не уверен, что они завоюют рынок мобильной разраюотки, но поживем-увидим. В любом случае это сложно назвать печальным концом платформы.

Пятое. Не забывайте про очень активно развивающееся направление Azure.

Шестое. Невысокий интерес к десктоп-приложениям вполне объясним нынешними тенденциями. Однако даже тут нужно поискать что-то лучше WPF.

По рынку труда я могу сказать, что когда мне доводилось искать работу, количество вакансий было всегда примерно одинаковым - никакого падения я не замечал.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за исчерпывающий и обнадеживающий ответ. Все мои товарищи учат Java  и поэтому я для них являюсь изгоем. Вот они мне собственно и наговорили гадостей про c# потом я взглянул на статистику и вот разнервничался.

Comment: Если бы я вернулся на 8 лет назад, то выбрал бы Джаву, честно :). Вакансий -- пруд пруди, и зарплаты хорошие.

Comment: Все было бы совсем хорошо (язык-то действительно производит очень приятное впечатление), если бы не одно (но очень весомое обстоятельство) -- Microsoft.

--

Кстати, [еще один ресурс](https://www.openhub.net/languages/compare?measure=contributors&percent=true&l0=c&l1=csharp&l2=cpp&l3=java&l4=php&l5=python&l6=-1&commit=Update) с данными о популярности языков.

Comment: Вот и я че-то волнуюсь. Ну ладно Java, но C++ и C впереди - вот что вызывает непонимание

Comment: @polyakov_s, пару лет назад было тут, на ХК, [обсуждение причин популярности C](http://hashcode.ru/questions/139077)

Comment: Да уж, забавно было почитать ))) Вот и меня удивляет, что в целом ИТ разбивается на экосистемы, где у каждой такой системы свой набор инструментов и пр. , и очень странно, что вакансий на с++ больше чем на c#.

Comment: >Ну ладно Java, но C++ и C впереди - вот что вызывает непонимание

@polyakov_s вы смешиваете теплое с мягким. Си и C# - языки с очень разными сферами применения, поэтому вряд ли стоит придавать особое значение их популярности относительно друг друга. Более того, эти графики популярности на мой взгляд довольно субъективно отражают популярность того или иного языка. Скорее всего они отражают ситуацию вообще в мире, тогда как конкретно в России или на Украине ситуация может быть совершенно иной

Comment: >Все было бы совсем хорошо (язык-то действительно производит очень приятное впечатление), если бы не одно (но очень весомое обстоятельство) -- Microsoft

ну а в чем проблема-то? По-моему, это утверждение, что, дескать, @Microsoft- корпорация зла" собственно тем и плохо, что это стереотип. В чем-то верный, но все же стереотип.